# sql group by date when same data

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

This is a bit too complex for me, so I wanted to ask for help...

I have data in a table like this:

```
 |   element     |     title      |      date       |    clicks   |

     vitrina           hello          2013-12-01           100      
     banner            hello          2013-12-01           100
     banner            hello          2013-12-02           100
     vitrina           hello          2013-12-02           100
     vitrina           hello          2013-12-03           100
     vitrina           hellox         2013-12-04           100
```

Basically, I want to join all rows that have same elements with different dates and sum the clicks.

results:

```
 |   element     |     title      |      date                    |    clicks   |

     vitrina           hello          2013-12-01 a 2013-12-03           300
     banner            hello          2013-12-01 a 2013-12-02           200
     vitrina           hellox         2013-12-04                        100
```

Im using PHP and I was going to do a normal query and then compare the rows and do it with loops and stuff, but I guess there has to be a way to query the data like this.

Hope you can help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple aggregation query:

```
SELECT element, 
       title, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN Min(date) <> Max(date) THEN Concat(Min(date), ' a ', Max(date)) 
           ELSE Min(date) 
         END )     AS date, 
       Sum(clicks) AS clicks 
FROM   t 
GROUP  BY element, 
          title;
```

Depending on the data type for `date` you may have to format it using `date_format()`.